# Advanced Parser Subclass No value - Php

Tags: php, parsing

I am using `Advanced Parser` I made this code that extracts the value of the class "text-brand"
However, I want to make the search more exact. Like this but it doesn't work.

`"//*[@class='text-brand']",` //This way it works but it's not so exact

How can I make it detect the subclass?

`"//*[@class='product-price text-brand']",`
In this 2nd code I say that the main class is this
"product-price" and that "text-brand" is inside it.

What am I doing wrong?

As an additional note I am using the famous variable `$this->xpathScalar($paths)`

Answer (score 0):

Solved - **Valid answer**:

```
//div[@class='product-price']/ins/span[@class='text-brand']
```